# how to deploy java application with native code from 64 bit windows to 32 bit windows?

Tags: java, windows, dll, native, jline

i hope caps lock haters are now pleased and in paradise. as you can see, all letters are small. enjoy yourself.

anyway, i have a question about java.
i have application written in java which uses some external libraries (jansi, and jline to be exact).

i am writing application in windows which is 64 bit, and i compile it, and create a build (clean and build in net beans), and start my application in the same windows i used to build it, and it works fine.

external libraries contain native code (for example jline contains code which calls some dll files (jline library has jline32.dll and jline64.dll files)).

both files are present in library folders, and it works on my 64 bit windows.

and my question is, if i wish to run the same application on 32 bit windows, what do i need to do?

do i need to build it on 32 bit windows so that jline uses 32 bit jline dll, or do i need to do something else? or do i not need to do anything.

i mean, my application does not use this dlls. they are used internally                    by jline library.

okay, thanx for reading.

Comment: Have you tested your application on a 32bit system? What happened? Usually if a library loads native code, you don't need to do anything, it's supposed to handle different platforms. But you never know for sure. So any test results?

Comment: hello,
not yet no.
my problem is that i do not have 32 bit versions of windows on computer, only 64 bit.

i gave this application to my friend who has 32 bit windows to test it and he reported to me that he could not start it, and that it threw him an error saying that it does not support 64 bit jvm.

so i am looking up what happened, so i asked here to see weather i need to do something before running my program on 32 bit windows.

i will probably install 32 bit windows, and looked it up in the next few days. but for now, i know only what he told me.

Comment: Ah, that reminds me, you can install a 32-bit JVM on your Windows and it should give you similar result.

Comment: thanx, i will try that.